# Analyzed bundle 'dump' with 0 classes

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

In the current configuration, I am using a jacoco-agent in the tcpserver mode for web application deployed on the serve node. Also, using jacoco-maven plugin to generate dump and report from my local node. I am able to get the dump in my local node by task mvn jacoco:dump. But when trying to generate the report against dump file by task mvn jacoco:report, getting "**Analyzed bundle 'dump' with 0 classes**".

Pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <address>*.*.*.*</address>
                <destFile>/app/jacoco_agent/new.exec</destFile>
                <port>7906</port>
                <reset>true</reset>
                <append>false</append>
            </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>dump</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>/app/jacoco_agent/new.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>/app/jacoco_agent/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>/target/classes</includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I generate a report by using jacoco-maven plugin?

Successfully able to generate a report by jacococli.jar.

java -jar ~/Downloads/jacoco-0.7.10-20171007.201717-57/lib/jacococli.jar report /app/jacoco_agent/new.exec --classfiles /target/classes --html report

Please help me to understand what's wrong, I am doing here with jacoco-maven plugin configuration?

Thanks